# how to find the min and max of x,y and Z in a 3D convex hull?

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull

I have a point cloud (P) with 100 points in 3D space. I want to know more about its corresponding convex-hull. My question is how to calculate the minimum and maximum of x,y,z in the P's convex hull?

Maybe the question can be asked in this form:
I was wondering if the points with minimum and maximum x,y and z coordination among of P points are placed on the boundary of P's convex hull?

for example s1 (x1,x2,x3) while x1 is the minimum x between P points, or S2 (x2,y2,z2) while y2 is the maximum y between P points... Now, my questions are:

1. are s1 and s2 placed on the boundary of P's convex hull?
2. is x1 the minimum x of the P's convex hull as well? (or y2 the maximum y of the P's convex hull?)

**In fact, are xmin,xmax; ymin, ymax; zmin and zmax among of the P points are xmin,xmax; ymin, ymax; zmin and zmax of the P's convex hull too? and if no, how can I compute these 6 items for the P's convex hull?**

Comment: Isn't this better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ ? If this in in fact a programming question, please show your code so far and set the appropriate language/tool tag(s).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually it is not a programming problem. it is a conceptual problem that I need to know its answer first.

Comment: `Actually it is not a programming problem.` - then it is off-topic here, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, the vertices of the hull are the most "external".